# where and whereIn suddenly stops working in laravel api

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

In my laravel api am using eloquent query with where condition like this. it was woriking fine before not it is not returning data . when i remove where and whereIn from query then it works fine.In tinker it is fetching data with where and whereIn .

Here is the query

```
    WorkingOrders::whereIn('status',[8,9])->where('gang_boss',auth()->user()->id)->orderBy('id','desc')->get();
```

whole controller is here

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\GeneralApi;

use App\Events\ConfirmOrder;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Models\Admin\Gang;
use App\Models\Admin\RightHandMan;
use App\Models\Admin\Staff;
use App\Models\Admin\StaffPivot;
use App\Models\Admin\Worker;
use App\Models\Admin\WorkerArrival;
use App\Models\Admin\WorkSheet;
use App\Models\WorkingOrders;
use App\Notifications\CustomNotification;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class WorkOrderController extends Controller

{


    public function workOrdersCompletedCancelled($user_id)
    {
        $role_id =  Auth::guard('staff_api')->user()->roles()->first()->id;
        $work_orders =  WorkingOrders::when($role_id == 2, function ($q) use ($user_id) {
            return $q->where('ranch', $user_id);
        })->when($role_id == 4, function ($q) use ($user_id) {
                return $q->where('right_hand_man_id', $user_id);
            })->when($role_id == 8, function ($q) use ($user_id) {
                return $q->where('supervisor', $user_id);
            })->when($role_id == 3, function ($q) use ($user_id) {
                $gang_ids = DB::table('worker_gang')->where('worker_id', $user_id)->pluck('gang_id')->toArray();
                $boss_ids = Gang::where('id', $gang_ids)->pluck('boss_id')->toArray();
                return $q->whereIn('gang_boss', $boss_ids);
            })->when($role_id == 10, function ($q) use ($user_id) {
                return $q->where('truck', $user_id);
            })->when($role_id == 1, function ($q) use ($user_id) {
                return $q->where('agent', $user_id);
            })->when($role_id == 9, function ($q) use ($user_id) {
                return $q->where('gang_boss', $user_id);
            })->whereIn('status', [0, 9])->with('gang_boss_details.bosses')
            ->with('type_of_cut_details')
            ->with('type_of_damage_details')
            ->with('number_of_boxes_details')
            ->with('size_of_boxes_details')
            ->with('packaging_company_details.packaging_companies')
            ->with('cutting_company_details:id,name')->with('supervisor_details:id,name')->with('agent_details:id,name')
            ->with('packaging_company_details:id,name')->with('truck_details:id,name')->with('ranch_details.ranch_owners')->with('right_hand_man:id,name')->with('weighing_machine_details:id,name,address,longitude,latitude')->with('worksheet')->orderBy('id', 'desc')->limit(20)->get();
        return response()->json($work_orders);
    }
    public function workOrders($boss_id)
    {
        $work_orders =  WorkingOrders::where('gang_boss', $boss_id)
            ->with('type_of_cut_details')
            ->with('type_of_damage_details')
            ->with('number_of_boxes_details')
            ->with('size_of_boxes_details')
            ->with('packaging_company_details.packaging_companies')
            ->with('gang_boss_details.bosses')->with('cutting_company_details:id,name')->with('supervisor_details:id,name')->with('agent_details:id,name')
            ->with('packaging_company_details')->with('truck_details:id,name')->with('ranch_details.ranch_owners')->with('right_hand_man:id,name')->with('weighing_machine_details:id,name,address,longitude,latitude')->with('worksheet')->orderBy('id', 'desc')->limit(20)->get();
        return response()->json($work_orders);
    }

    public function workOrderDetail($work_order_id)
    {
        $work_order =  WorkingOrders::with('cutting_company_details:id,name')
            ->with('type_of_cut_details')
            ->with('type_of_damage_details')
            ->with('number_of_boxes_details')
            ->with('size_of_boxes_details')
            ->with('packaging_company_details.packaging_companies')
            ->with('supervisor_details')->with('gang_boss_details.bosses')->with('agent_details')->with('ranch_details.ranch_owners')
            ->with('packaging_company_details')->with('weighing_machine_details:id,name,address,longitude,latitude')->with('worksheet')->with('truck_details.trucks')->with('right_hand_man')->find($work_order_id);
        return response()->json($work_order);
    }

    public function markOrderComplete($id)
    {
        $work_order = WorkingOrders::find($id);

         DB::table('notifications')->where('data','like','%'.$id.'%')->delete();
         $work_order->update(['status'=>9,'truck_delivered_fruit_at'=>date('Y-m-d H:i:s')]);

    }

    public function getRightHandManList()
    {
        $staff_child =   StaffPivot::where('staff_id', auth()->user()->id)->pluck('child_id')->toArray();
        $staff_role =  DB::table('staff_role')->whereIn('staff_id', $staff_child)->where('role_id', 4)->pluck('staff_id')->toArray();
        $staffs = Staff::whereIn('id', $staff_role)->pluck('id');
        $right_hand_men =  RightHandMan::whereIn('staff_id', $staffs)->with('staffs')->get();
        return response()->json($right_hand_men);
    }

    public function saveRightHandManList($right_hand_man, $work_order_id)
    {
        $work_order = WorkingOrders::find($work_order_id);
        if($work_order->status == 8){
            $status = 8;
        }else{
            $status = 3;
        }
        $work_order->update(['right_hand_man_id' => $right_hand_man, 'status' => $status,'confirmed_by_boss_at'=>date('Y-m-d H:i:s')]);
        $working_order = WorkingOrders::find($work_order_id);
        $appDetails = [
            'actionText' => Auth::user()->name . ' Se te asignó la orden de corte #' . $work_order_id,
            'actionURL' => "/work-order-detail/2/{$working_order->longitude}/{$working_order->latitude}",
        ];
        $rhm = Staff::find($right_hand_man);
        $rhm->notify(new CustomNotification($appDetails));
        event(new ConfirmOrder($working_order));
        return response()->json(['success' => 'Bañero asignado correctamente']);
    }

    public function getWorkSheet($work_order_id,$time)
    {
        $work_sheet = WorkSheet::where('work_order_id', $work_order_id)->first();
        $work_order = WorkingOrders::find($work_order_id);
        if($work_order->status == 8){
            $status = 8;
        }else{
            $status = 6;
        }
        $work_order->update(['status'=>$status,'arrival_to_ranch_at'=>date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime($time))]);
        return response()->json($work_sheet);
    }

    public function saveWorkSheet($work_order_id, $column_name, $column_value)
    {
        if ($column_value == 'null') {
            $column_value = null;
        }
        $work_sheet =  WorkSheet::where('work_order_id', $work_order_id)->update([$column_name => $column_value]);
        return response()->json(['status' => true, 'message' => 'Hoja de campo guardada correctamente']);
    }

    public function addWorker(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'name' => 'required',
            'password' => 'required',
            'location' => 'required',
            'longitude' => 'required',
            'latitude' => 'required',
            'govt_id' => 'required',
            'phone_number' => 'required',
            'social_security_number' => 'required|unique:staffs,social_security_number',
            'time_as_worker' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required|email|unique:staffs,email'
        ]);
        $staff =   Staff::create([
            'name' => $request->name, 'password' => bcrypt($request->password), 'email' => $request->email, 'govt_id' => $request->govt_id,
            'social_security_number' => $request->social_security_number, 'phone_number' => $request->phone_number
        ]);
        DB::insert('insert into staff_role (role_id, staff_id) values (?, ?)', [3, $staff->id]);
        Worker::create(['staff_id' => $staff->id, 'time_as_worker' => $request->time_as_worker, 'address' => $request->location, 'latitude' => $request->latitude, 'longitude' => $request->longitude]);
        StaffPivot::create(['staff_id' => $request->boss_id, 'child_id' => $staff->id]);
        return response()->json(['status' => true, 'message' => 'Cortador creado correctamente']);
    }
    public function addRightHandMan(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'name' => 'required',
            'password' => 'required',
            'location' => 'required',
            'longitude' => 'required',
            'latitude' => 'required',
            'govt_id' => 'required',
            'phone_number' => 'required',
            'social_security_number' => 'required|unique:staffs,social_security_number',
            'time_as_right_hand_man' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required|email|unique:staffs,email'
        ]);
        $staff =   Staff::create([
            'name' => $request->name, 'password' => bcrypt($request->password), 'email' => $request->email, 'govt_id' => $request->govt_id,
            'social_security_number' => $request->social_security_number, 'phone_number' => $request->phone_number
        ]);
        DB::insert('insert into staff_role (role_id, staff_id) values (?, ?)', [4, $staff->id]);
        RightHandMan::create(['staff_id' => $staff->id, 'time_as_right_hand_man' => $request->time_as_right_hand_man, 'address' => $request->location, 'latitude' => $request->latitude, 'longitude' => $request->longitude]);
        StaffPivot::create(['staff_id' => $request->boss_id, 'child_id' => $staff->id]);
        return response()->json(['status' => true, 'message' => 'Bañero creado correctamente']);
    }

    public function getGangWorkers($gang_boss_id, $work_order_id)
    {
        $gang =  Gang::where('boss_id', $gang_boss_id)->first();
        $arrived_workers =  WorkerArrival::select('worker_id')->where('work_order_id', $work_order_id)->pluck('worker_id');
        return response()->json(['workers' => $gang->workers()->get(), 'arrived_workers' => $arrived_workers]);
    }
    public function getGangWorkersOnly($gang_boss_id)
    {
        $gang =  Gang::where('boss_id', $gang_boss_id)->first();

        return response()->json(['workers' => $gang->workers()->get()]);
    }

    public function storeWorkerArrival(Request $request)
    {


         WorkerArrival::where('work_order_id', $request->work_order_id)->delete();
        foreach ($request->worker_ids as $id) {
            if(!WorkerArrival::where('worker_id',$id)->where('work_order_id',$request->work_order_id)->exists()){
            WorkerArrival::create(['worker_id' => $id, 'work_order_id' => $request->work_order_id, 'is_reached' => 1]);
            }
        }
        $work_order = WorkingOrders::find($request->work_order_id);
        if($work_order->status == 8){
            $status = 8;
        }else{
            $status = 5;
        }
        $work_order->update(['status'=>$status,'arrival_to_mp_at'=>date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime($request->time))]);
        event(new ConfirmOrder(WorkingOrders::find($request->work_order_id)));
        return response()->json(['status' => true, 'message' => 'Los cortadores que llegaron han sido registrados']);
    }

    public function getBossRightHandMan($boss_id)
    {
        $staff_child =   StaffPivot::where('staff_id', $boss_id)->pluck('child_id')->toArray();
        $staff_role =  DB::table('staff_role')->whereIn('staff_id', $staff_child)->where('role_id', 4)->pluck('staff_id')->toArray();
        $staffs = Staff::whereIn('id', $staff_role)->get();
        return response()->json($staffs);
    }

    public function getBossWorkers($boss_id)
    {
        // $gang =  Gang::where('boss_id', $boss_id)->first();

        // return response()->json(['workers' => $gang->workers()->get()]);
        $staff_child =   StaffPivot::where('staff_id', $boss_id)->pluck('child_id')->toArray();
        $staff_role =  DB::table('staff_role')->whereIn('staff_id', $staff_child)->where('role_id', 3)->pluck('staff_id')->toArray();
        $staffs = Staff::whereIn('id', $staff_role)->get();
        $gang =  Gang::where('boss_id', $boss_id)->first();

        return response()->json(['staff'=>$staffs,'workers'=>$gang->workers()->pluck('worker_id')->toArray()]);
    }

    public function deleteWorker(Request $request)
    {

        // Staff::find($request->worker_id)->delete();
        // Worker::where('staff_id', $request->worker_id)->delete();
        // $gang = Gang::where('boss_id', auth()->user()->id)->first();
        // DB::table('worker_gang')->where('worker_id', $request->worker_id)->where('gang_id', $gang->id)->delete();

        $gang = Gang::where('boss_id', auth()->user()->id)->first();
        StaffPivot::where('staff_id', auth()->user()->id)->where('child_id' , $request->worker_id)->delete();
        DB::table('worker_gang')->where('worker_id', $request->worker_id)->where('gang_id', $gang->id)->delete();

        return response()->json(['success', 'Cortador elimando de tu lista de trabajadores']);
    }

    public function checkExistingStaff(Request $request)
    {
        if (Staff::where('social_security_number', $request->social_security_number)->exists()) {
            return response()->json(['exists' => true, 'data' => Staff::where('social_security_number', $request->social_security_number)->first()]);
        }
        return response()->json(['exists' => false]);
    }
    public function addToMyProfile(Request $request)
    {
        if (!StaffPivot::where('staff_id', auth()->user()->id)->where('child_id', $request->child_id)->exists()) {
            StaffPivot::create(['staff_id' => auth()->user()->id, 'child_id' => $request->child_id]);
            return response()->json(['message' => 'Agregado correctamente a tu lista de trabajadores']);
        }
        return response()->json(['message' => 'Ya existe este usuario en tu lista de trabajadores']);
    }
    public function satffDetail($staff_id)
    {
        $satff = Staff::find($staff_id);
        return response()->json($satff);
    }

    public function addToGang(Request $request)
    {

        $gang =  Gang::where('boss_id', auth()->user()->id)->first();
        if (!DB::table('worker_gang')->where('worker_id', $request->worker_id)->where('gang_id', $gang->id)->exists()) {
            DB::table('worker_gang')->insert(['worker_id' => $request->worker_id, 'gang_id' => $gang->id]);
        }
        return response()->json(['status' => true, 'message' => 'Cortador asignado a la cuadrilla']);
    }


    public function removeWorkerFromGang(Request $request)
    {
        $gang =  Gang::where('boss_id', auth()->user()->id)->first();
        if (DB::table('worker_gang')->where('worker_id', $request->worker_id)->where('gang_id', $gang->id)->exists()) {
            DB::table('worker_gang')->where('worker_id', $request->worker_id)->where('gang_id', $gang->id)->delete();
            return response()->json(['status' => true, 'message' => 'Eliminado de la cuadrilla']);
        }
        return response()->json(['status' => true, 'message' => 'Este cortador no está en la cuadrilla']);
    }

    public function removeRHMFromWorkOrder(Request $request)
    {


        StaffPivot::where('child_id', $request->rhm)->where('staff_id', auth()->user()->id)->delete();

        return response()->json(['success', 'Bañero elimanado de tu lista de trabajadores']);
    }
    public function OrderComplete($id,$time)
    {
        $work_order = WorkingOrders::find($id);
        if($work_order->status == 8){
            $status = 8;
        }else{
            $status = 7;
        }

        $work_order->update(['status' => $status,'boss_marked_completed_at'=>date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime($time))]);
        return response()->json(['status' => true, 'message' => 'Orden de corte completada']);
    }
    public function acceptance(Request $request)
    {

        if ($request->role == 'ranch') {

            WorkingOrders::where('id', $request->work_order_id)->update(['ranch_signature' => $request->acceptance]);
        }
        if ($request->role == 'supervisor') {
            WorkingOrders::where('id', $request->work_order_id)->update(['supervisor_signature' => $request->acceptance]);
        }

        return response()->json(['success' => 'Acción completada']);
    }


    public function storeWorkerData(Request $request)
    {

       WorkingOrders::find($request->work_order_id)->update(['boss_marked_completed_at'=>date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),'arrival_to_ranch_at'=>date('Y-m-d H:i:s')]);
        WorkSheet::where('work_order_id', $request->work_order_id)->update(['worker_data' => json_encode($request->worker_data),'number_of_box'=>json_encode($request->number_of_boxes)]);
        return response()->json(['success' => 'Datos del cortador guardados']);
    }

    public function getBossPayments(Request $request)
    {

        if($request->keyword !='false'){
        $staff_ids = Staff::select('id')->where('name','like',"%{$request->keyword}%")->pluck('id');
        $work_orders =  WorkingOrders::select('id','cutting_company','ranch','cutting_company_amount','final_kg','boss_amount')->with(['cutting_company_details:id,name','ranch_details:id,name','worksheet:work_order_id,worker_data,number_of_box'])->whereIn('status',[8,9])->where('gang_boss',auth()->user()->id)
        ->where(function($query)use($request,$staff_ids){
          $query->orWhere('id',$request->keyword)->orWhereIn('ranch',$staff_ids)->orWhereIn('cutting_company',$staff_ids);
        })->orderBy('id','desc')->get();
        foreach($work_orders as $work_order)
        {
            $work_order->setAttribute('payment',$this->getTotalAmountToPayToWorkers($work_order)['total_payment']);

        }
        return response()->json(['work_orders'=>$work_orders]);
    }else{

        $work_orders =  WorkingOrders::select('id','cutting_company','ranch','cutting_company_amount','final_kg','boss_amount')->with(['cutting_company_details:id,name','ranch_details:id,name','worksheet:work_order_id,worker_data,number_of_box'])->whereIn('status',[8,9])->where('gang_boss',auth()->user()->id)->orderBy('id','desc')->get();
        dd($work_orders);
        foreach($work_orders as $work_order)
        {
            $work_order->setAttribute('payment',$this->getTotalAmountToPayToWorkers($work_order)['total_payment']);

        }

        return response()->json(['work_orders'=>$work_orders]);
    }

    }

    public function getWorkOrderWorkerPayment($work_order_id)
    {

      $work_order =  WorkingOrders::with(['worksheet:work_order_id,worker_data,number_of_box','cutting_company_details:id,name','ranch_details:id,name'])->select('id','boss_amount','boss_marked_completed_at','cutting_company','ranch','date_of_work')->where('id',$work_order_id)->first();

      $work_order->setAttribute('total_amount_to_pay', $this->getTotalAmountToPayToWorkers($work_order)['total_payment']);

      return response()->json(['worker_payment_data'=>$this->getTotalAmountToPayToWorkers($work_order)['worker_payment_data'],'work_order'=>$work_order]);
    }

    public function getTotalAmountToPayToWorkers($work_order)
    {

        $total_amount_to_pay = 0;
        $worker_payment_data = [];
        $work_sheet= $work_order->worksheet;

        $data = json_decode($work_sheet->worker_data,true );
        $number_of_boxes = json_decode($work_sheet->number_of_box,true);
        foreach ((array)$data as $key => $worker_data){

            $box = 0;
            if(key_exists($key,$number_of_boxes))
            {
                $box =(int)$number_of_boxes[$key];
            }
           array_push($worker_payment_data,array('worker_id'=>explode("-",$key)[0],'photo_url'=>Staff::find(explode("-",$key)[0])->photo_url ?? '','worker_name'=>explode("-",$key)[1],'number_of_boxes'=>$box,'comment'=>$worker_data,
           'amount_to_pay'=>$box * (float)$work_order->boss_amount ));
           $total_amount_to_pay += ($box * (float)$work_order->boss_amount);
        }

        $worker_payment_data = collect($worker_payment_data);
        return array('total_payment'=>$total_amount_to_pay,'worker_payment_data'=>$worker_payment_data);
    }

   public function submitBossAmount($work_order_id,Request $request)
   {
        WorkingOrders::find($work_order_id)->update(['boss_amount'=>$request->boss_amount]);

        return response()->json(['status'=>true,'message'=>'Boss amount submitted successfully']);
   }
   public function getWorkerPayments(Request $request,$worker_id)
   {

       $staff_ids = Staff::select('id')->where('name','like',"%{$request->keyword}%")->pluck('id');
       $work_order_ids = WorkSheet::select('work_order_id')->where('worker_data','like',"%{$worker_id}%")->pluck('work_order_id');
       $work_orders =  WorkingOrders::select('id','cutting_company','ranch','cutting_company_amount','final_kg','boss_amount','date_of_work','boss_marked_completed_at')
       ->with(['cutting_company_details:id,name','ranch_details:id,name'])
       ->whereIn('status',[8,9])->whereIn('id',$work_order_ids)
       ->where(function($query)use($staff_ids,$request){
           $query->where('id',$request->keyword)->orWhereIn('ranch',$staff_ids)->orWhereIn('cutting_company',$staff_ids);
       })->orderBy('id','desc')->get();
       foreach($work_orders as $work_order)
       {
        $payment = $this->getTotalAmountToPayToWorkersForWorkPortal($work_order,$worker_id);
        $work_order->setAttribute('payment',$payment['total_payment']);
        $work_order->setAttribute('worker_payment_data',$payment['worker_payment_data']);
        $work_order->setAttribute('total_amount_to_pay',$payment['total_payment']);

    }
       return response()->json(['work_orders'=>$work_orders,'worker_payment_data']);
    }
    public function getTotalAmountToPayToWorkersForWorkPortal($work_order,$worker_id)
    {
        $total_amount_to_pay = 0;
        $worker_payment_data = [];
        $work_sheet= $work_order->worksheet;
        $worker_data = json_decode($work_sheet->worker_data,true );
        $number_of_boxes = json_decode($work_sheet->number_of_box,true);
        foreach ($worker_data as $key => $worker_data){
            $box = 0;
            if(key_exists($key,$number_of_boxes))
            {
                $box =(int)$number_of_boxes[$key];
            }
            if(explode("-",$key)[0]  == $worker_id){
             $worker_payment_data = array('worker_id'=>explode("-",$key)[0],'photo_url'=>Staff::find(explode("-",$key)[0])->photo_url ?? '','worker_name'=>explode("-",$key)[1],'number_of_boxes'=> $box ,'comment'=>$worker_data,
           'amount_to_pay'=> $box  * (float)$work_order->boss_amount );
           $total_amount_to_pay += ( $box  * (float)$work_order->boss_amount);
            }
        }

        $worker_payment_data = collect($worker_payment_data);

        return array('total_payment'=>$total_amount_to_pay,'worker_payment_data'=>$worker_payment_data);
    }
}
```

This is the full controller . I also tried to type cast variable which are using in where condition but nothing works.

Comment: probably `auth()->user()->id` is null , you can try `auth('api')->user()->id`

Comment: still until remove `whereIn` also it will not work

Comment: Show us the rest of your controller - it is something you are doing and we can see very little of what you are doing.

Comment: I updated my question please have a look

Comment: "*In tinker it is fetching data*" - `auth()` won't work in Tinker, I think? So you are probably hard-coding some value to test in Tinker?  If that works, and the normal `auth()` code does not, it seems like that is the only difference, and that must be the problem, right?  Have you *triple-* checked that code is doing what you expect, eg `dd(auth()->user()->id)`?